# Why is AWS ECS Fargate not showing any files in my Jupyter Notebook server container?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, amazon-ecs, alpine-linux, aws-fargate

I have a Jupyter Notebook docker container with an alpine linux base OS for the image that when built and ran locally works just fine. It will show the contents of the OS and the folder I copied data into the image as expected. However, when the image is pushed up to AWS ECR and pulled down to be setup as a task in AWS ECS Fargate, it shows no files.

I've updated my 'jupyter_notebook_config.py' file in the following way:

```
from IPython.lib import passwd

c.NotebookApp.ip = "*"
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = "*"
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.NotebookApp.password = passwd("place_your_passwd_here")
```

Via the AWS ALB, I'm able to successfully log into the Jupyter Notebook server container on Fargate, but when viewing, it shows nothing but 'server: Forbidden':

[image]

I've looked around a lot of docs and forums about this but when getting into containers, there's not as much clear recommendations for debugging this. Any links or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any volumes with your docker image?. Can you please share a snippet of Dockerfile/compose and task definition details?.

Comment: Thanks @Imran but it turned out to be a networking issue with AWS' ALB service in conjunction with the AWS ECS Fargate service.

Comment: How did you manage to use a jupyter notebook in a container in aws? I'm trying to do the same but it's very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable 'sticky sessions' on you're ALB using Terraform. If you spin up with CloudFormation stack, it'll most likely already be enabled. This fixes the problem!